# HTML Form is showing up even though PHP "if" statement is not met

Tags: php, html, if-statement, form-submit

I am quite new at programming (especially in PHP).
Anyway, I have been attempting for a bit now to create a log-in page that utilizes both PHP and HTML.

The main idea is if it's the first time the user has come to the log-in page, then they have to click a "submit" button first; which will then reload the page but now will have a  where the user will input information to call up another PHP script.

I have attempted the following codes to achieve this:

```
          <form method = "post"
                action = "Sign-In2.html">


          <p>
          <br />
            <input type = "submit"
                   name = "returnUser"
                   value = "Click To Log In">
          </P>
          </form>

          <?php

          if (isset($_POST['returnUser'])) {

          ?>    

          <form method = "post"
                action = "Login2.php">

            <p>
            <br />
            In Honor Of:
            <input type = "text"
                   name = "userName"
                   value = "">

            <br />
            EDGE Code:
            <input type = "password"
                   name = "edgeCode"
                   value = "">

            <br /><br />
            <input type = "checkbox"
                   name = "rememberUser"
                   value = "remembered">Remember Me

            <br />
            <input type = "submit"
                   value = "Log Me In">

            </p>
            </form>

          <?php

          } else {

          } //end if

          ?>
```

From everything I have read online (from this site and others), I am under the impression that my code includes two forms and a PHP "if" statement.

The FIRST form just provides a "submit" button that is named "returnUser" and reloads the page (which is named Sign-In2.html).

Then PHP jumps in and runs a condition check. If the "submit" button from the FIRST form has in fact been clicked, then the SECOND form will be run. If it has NOT been clicked, then nothing happens.

SO MY ISSUE is that when I run this this code from localhost WAMPserver, BOTH forms show up! I am unable to understand or find out why not just the first form but both are showing up when I load the page! I just want the first submit button to show up so I can click on it and refresh the page with the input fields from the second form :(
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Note: The second form and its phpscript both run no problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the expected result. Button only, then when I click on it, button and form.

Answer (score 1):

You want to display one form or the other, so use the `if` statement to choose which one you want to display. What your code is doing at the moment is displaying the first form - then if you have a `$_POST` value sent, displaying the second one.

Changing your code to the below will display one form or the other, depending on if the `$_POST` is set or not.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['returnUser']))
{
?>    

    <form method = "post"
    action = "">

    <p>
    <br />
    In Honor Of:
    <input type = "text"
       name = "userName"
       value = "">

    <br />
    EDGE Code:
    <input type = "password"
       name = "edgeCode"
       value = "">

    <br /><br />
    <input type = "checkbox"
       name = "rememberUser"
       value = "remembered">Remember Me

    <br />
    <input type = "submit"
       value = "Log Me In">

    </p>
    </form>

<?php
} 
else 
{
?>

    <form method = "post"
    action = "">


    <p>
    <br />
    <input type = "submit"
       name = "returnUser"
       value = "Click To Log In">
    </P>
    </form>

    <?php
} //end if

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Fluffeh! Your code makes a lot of sense! However, I just tried your code out and unfortunately it behaved just like last time in that both forms showed up. The "Log Me In" button is now under the input form :( I am starting to get the feeling that my codes are not being parsed correctly, in that the "if" statement is not actually taking any effect. Is there any way I can check? OH, and I am not sure if this makes a difference on   how the code works, but I am running this page as a HTML file instead of a PHP file at the moment.

Comment: @PSEdge You will *need* to run it as a PHP file for the PHP goodies to work. Also, I updated the action on the form so that it points to itself which is what is wanted for this.

Answer (score 0):

change the File name `Sign-In2.html` to `Sign-In2.php` and same in form action.

Answer (score 0):

Is this by any chance a normal .html page?

By default, PHP doesn't run on those, so your `<?php ?>` tags are interpreted as normal HTML tags.

Change the file's extension to PHP to solve it.